# How is the expression of a DataColumn evaluated when the column contains a non-primitive (reference) type

Tags: c#, .net, dataview, datacolumn

I have a `DataView` in which the `DataColumn.DataType` of one of the columns is not a primitive type, but the type of a class within the project (let's call it `MyClass`).

`MyClass` implements `IComparable`, overrides `Equals(object obj)`, and implements `operator ==(MyClass x, MyClass y)`, `operator !=(MyClass x, MyClass y)`, `operator >(MyClass x, MyClass y)` and `operator <(MyClass x, MyClass y)`.

Sorting the `DataView` by this column calls `IComparable.CompareTo()` as expected and works fine.

However, if another column references this column in an expression, eg.

```
IIF(MyClass1 = MyClass2, 'True', 'False')
```

then an exception  is thrown:

> Cannot perform '=' operation on `MyClass` and `MyClass`

Debugging proves that none of the above comparison methods/operators ever gets called.

Can anyone explain what mechanism is used to evaluate `DataColumn.Expression`, and why `DataView.Sort` can call the relevant methods on the class, but the expression evaluator can't?

Comment: Why you don't use Linq-To-DataTable where you dont need limited "hacks" like the `Expression`-syntax and can use any code you like?

Comment: Wouldn't that be == ?

Comment: @CetinBasoz: No, that's not C# it's not even VB.NET, it's just a string. You can read about the syntax [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I see, I never tried to use it. I too think Linq is a better choice (I wouldn't even use a DataTable in between).

Comment: `DataColumn.Expression` uses its own little language that was really cool back when we didn't have LINQ, and is laughably limited and slow now. `Sort` admits a far simpler implementation that isn't bound by the limitations of this language, but parsing `a = b` into an arbitrary `.Equals` call is a bridge too far. [Here's the source for that, I think](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Filter/BinaryNode.cs,135). Note how the method has no support for anything that's not a known type.

Comment: Tim Schmelter - I'm not sure how Linq-To-Datatable would help me. Can you maybe point me to a relevant article?